# change fields value from other model

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In pos.quotation model we have state. so my goal is when state changes i want that boolean field in shoes.order named "handed" would change to true. i know how to do it if i would be doing it in one model, but struggle when i need to change field in other.

```
class pos_quotation(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.quotation"

    @api.onchange('state')
    def handed(self):
        shoes = self.env['shoes.order']
        for rec in self:
            if self.state == "delivery_success":
                rec.shoes.handed = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in onchange the self contains a dummy object when you change the values
nothing happen on the database layer. (opposite to depends compute field)

but the original value is passed in self._origin.

```py
@api.onchange('state')
def handed(self):
 if self.state == "delivery_success":
              # first try this if it work 
              self._origin.shoes.handed = True

              # if not working then you need to fetch the recorod
              # from the database first.
              shoes = self.env['shoes.order'].search[('id', '=', self.shoes.id)]

              shoes.handed = True
```

but doing this in onchange event may cause some problem imaging that the user has
changed his mind and click on cancel (changes are discared) but shoes.handed is 
al ready commited in database.

my propsition for you is to use related field.

```py
class pos_quotation(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.quotation"

    # i'm assuming that your m2o field is shoes
    # don't make readonly because you need to save it's changed value
    # when you hit save.
    handed = fields.Boolean(related="shoes.handed")

    @api.onchange('state')
    def handed(self):
        if self.state == "delivery_success": 
               self.handed = True
```

don't forget to add this field to the form view and make sure it's invisible 
so the user don't update the value manually

```xml
    <field name="handed" invisible="1"/>
```

hope you got the idea.